# Drawing and making notes with mouse on a pdf during presentation

Tags: educational, presentation

I am a teacher who is trying to make instructional videos during the corona lockdown. I want use a presentation for the instruction while recording the screen.

I use latex beamer for my presentations and I would like to use my mouse to make certain notes on the slides during the presentation as a replacement of my whiteboard in the classroom.

Microsoft PowerPoint has a built-in pen feature that allows the use of the mouse as a pen during a presentation. However, I refuse to use Powerpoint since the typesetting for equations and formulas is terrible.

Is there a similar freeware program that can present pdf presentations and allows drawings during a presentation? So far I have bad luck with pdfpresenter. It seems to be outdated.

I am a windows 10 and Linux mint user.

Could someone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use [Okular](https://okular.kde.org/) because it supports pdf annotations.

When you are presenting your document in Presentation mode (**View** > **Presentation**, or **Ctrl** + **Shift** + **P**), you can hover on the top of the slide to bring a toolbar to choose the color of the pen and several other options.

Answer (score 1):

In adobe you meet this need, follow a very simple guide...

https://bcourses.berkeley.edu/courses/1462694/pages/how-to-annotate-your-presentation-slides?module_item_id=15494654

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently looking for the same feature myself and found [pdfpc](https://github.com/pdfpc/pdfpc) to have this functionality, and some other nice things, like multi-monitor presentations with slide preview.  The interface is quite terse, but everything's described well in its man page.